# How to remove water based wood stain

Tags: walls

I refinished my kitchen cabinets. I got some water based wood stain on my kitchen wall. I tried to remove it with soap and water on a sponge. It did not work. How can I move it? My kitchen wall is painted with water based satin finished paint.